# What is the basis for a direct product of vectors?

Tags: vector-spaces

I know that If $A$ is a basis for $U$ and $B$ is a basis for $V$, then $A∪B$ is a basis for $U\oplus V$, but what is the basis for $U\otimes V$.

Comment: direct or tensor?

Comment: in a few words, $A\times B$, their cartesian product

Comment: @Randall, I don't know enough to know the difference between direct and tensor.

Comment: @janmarqz, so is $A\cap B$ a basis for the product?

Comment: no, because they are at different spaces

Comment: @MrDi  $U \otimes V$ is the tensor product, $U \times V$ the direct product.

Comment: @Randall, so if $A$ is a basis for $U$ and $B$ is a basis for $V$, what is the basis for $U⊗V$ and $U×V$?

Comment: Here, let me answer the 2nd : $U\times V$ is generated by pairs of the kind $$(a_1,0),...,(a_n,0), (0,b_1),...,(0,b_m),$$ where the $a_\in A$ and $b_j\in B$. For the 1st one needs new objects symbolized by $a_i\otimes b_j$ which are $nm$ in total.

Answer (score 0):

The tensor product $U\otimes V$ has the property:
For each **bilinear transformation** $Q:U\times V \to\mathbb F$ there exists an associated **linear transformation**
$L_Q:U\otimes V\to\mathbb F$ such that at basis elements
$$Q(a_i,b_j)=L_Q(a_i\otimes b_j).$$

The set $\mathbb F$ is the field where the spaces $U,V$ are constructed.